# Excluding a word within regular expression

Tags: computer-science, regular-language

So I'm not 100% sure this is the correct place to ask, but stackoverflow seems like it's usually a godsend for anything computer-sciencey so here we go.

I've been asked to produce a regular expression for all words in the alphabet {a,b}* which *do not* end with bba. I've come up with this:

```
(a U b)*( (aaa) U (aab) U (baa) U (bab) U (aba) U (abb) U (bbb) )
```

So that's a language which contains any combination of as and bs so long as the final three letters are NOT bba. I'm pretty sure this is correct and describes the given language.

However, I feel like this can be shortened somehow, that perhaps there's a way to cleverly write an exclusion of a certain word from a language in its regular expression.

(Note: this is regular expression in the context of finite automata, not regex for word comparison. Sadly I can only find information on the latter.)

Thanks for any and all help :)

Comment: Well there's also [cs.se]... That's even more computer-sciencey.

Comment: Whoops! I'll crosspost it there. Cheers :)

Comment: And indeed it is answered over there, trawling through stackoverflow wasn't a good use of my time after all.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is a duplicate of many questions over on computer science:

https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/66513/write-a-regex-to-match-string-that-does-not-contain-a-certain-pattern